# Hiding cursor on raspbian stretch chromium

Tags: raspbian, chromium, xorg

I'm running a RPi 3 as an infoscreen. Im just starting chromium with the xinit command from rc.local, so far so good. I'm having trouble to hide the cursor. When i do this from command line (SSH) when the screen is running this works just fine:

```
DISPLAY="0.0 ; export DISPLAY
unclutter -idle 0.1 -root
```

But I cant find out where to put this so this starts automaticly. It seems that setting DISPLAY in the rc.local file doesnt work. When i try to run unclutter without setting DISPLAY it can't open the display. Where do I set the DISPLAY variable at startup?

Answer (score 0):

I would find it better for the script to run at login, and this is how you would do it:

You can add your script executable command to the bottom of .bashrc that will run your script every time you log in.

Make sure you are in the pi folder:

```
$ cd ~
```

Create a file and write the script to run in the file:

```
$ sudo nano superscript
```

Save and exit: *Ctrl+X, Y, Enter*

Open up .bashrc for configuration:

```
$ sudo nano .bashrc
```

Scroll down (Down arrow key) to the bottom and add the line: ./superscript

Save and exit: *Ctrl+X, Y, Enter*